# Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter not working on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, atheros

**Solution 1**

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop alongside windows. I have an Atheros AR9485 adapter. It worked well for a few weeks and now won't work anymore although it still works for the windows. I have tried out some of the solutions suggested but it still doesn't work. This so what I have so far done and the answers I get;

```
$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
Error: missing module name.
FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi

$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi.conf
FATAL: Module iwlwifi.conf not found.

$ cd /etc
/etc$ ls
```

Here I find the directory *modprobe.d* but `modprobe` does not exist so I try

```
$ cd modprobe.d
modprobe.d: No such file or directory
```

Then I go back to the /etc and try

```
$ cd /etc
$ cd modprobe.d
/etc/modprobe.d$ ls
```

I find the file **iwlwifi.conf~** and try:

```
/etc/modprobe.d$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi.conf~
FATAL: Module iwlwifi.conf~ not found.

/etc/modprobe.d$ cd ~

$ sudo modprobe.d -r iwlwifi.conf~
sudo: modprobe.d: command not found
```

I had read a solution that was giving the steps below if I had succeeded. I tried to look for the .conf file and edited it as directed in the last part of this solution but it didn't work and I was unable to go beyond that;

Looks like this hardware has some problem with N configuration in WiFi.
Please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Now try to reconnect, if it helps follow below steps

1. Look into `/etc/modprobe.d` whether there are any file like `intel-5100-iwlwifi-disable11n.conf` then edit the file.

   ```
    sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/<filename_here>
   ```

   Edit the line that says

   ```
   options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
   ```

   to

   ```
   options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0
   ```

   Save and reboot.
2. If no file exists, create a new file

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
   ```

   Add a new line:

   ```
   options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
   ```

   Save and reboot.

**Solution 2:**

When solution 1 failed, I tried solution 2 as shown here below;

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
lsmod
iwconfig
rfkill list
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI
Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:061f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e047]
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
```

`lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
bnep                   19564  2 
rfcomm                 69070  0 
bluetooth             371874  10 bnep,rfcomm
vesafb                 13828  1 
lp                     17759  0
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 53014  0 
hid                   101512  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            62062  1 
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23527  0 
ahci                   25819  2 
libahci                31898  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               45546  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
r8169                  67341  0
mii                    13934  1 r8169
```

`iwconfig`

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list`

The last command did not give an output so I could not follow the instructions that were to come as shown below;

Deactivate the hardware encryption of the driver:

Code:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Any help either along these steps or any other solution will be appreciated.

Comment: The actions concerning iwlwifi are for a different (Intel) chipset and will be ineffective for your Atheros. I suggest you edit your question to remove it and add the result of the following: dmesg | grep ath

Answer (score 0):

- Download this driver `compat-drivers-3.9-rc4-2-su.tar.bz2` to a folder on your machine.
- Go to the folder and `unzip` the tar file using `tar xf compat-dri....`
- `cd` into the unzipped file and issue the following commands;

```
./scripts/driver-select ath9k
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo make unload
```

- Reboot your system.

Hopefully, it works now.