# Wireless connection doesn't work

Tags: wireless, atheros

So that's all, my wireless connection in Ubuntu doesn't work, how can I fix it?? Further info: I have an Asus K550C with "Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter"

Thank you

```
joan@joan-X550CC:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:38:0d:4d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7664 (7.6 KB)  TX bytes:7664 (7.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:f0:2f:6c:86:18  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

AND I'VE SEEN ALSO THIS COMMAND TO POST, IF IT IS NECESSARY HERE IT IS

```
joan@joan-X550CC:~$ sudo lshw -C network; lsb_release -a; uname -a; sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for joan: 
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 40:f0:2f:6c:86:18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-36-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: e0:3f:49:38:0d:4d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Linux joan-X550CC 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: please post an output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: already done :)

Comment: According to this result `*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface` and `0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes` your wireless is disabled and already have installed. do you physical shortcut key on your keyboard to turning ON/OFF your wifi? if yes please do it and then your wifi works well.

Comment: In laptop i have also windows and the wireless works, so I think that this is not the problem but it's true that whe i go to the folder networks or like that the "button" is disabled and I can't turn it on, ubuntu doesn't let me to turn it on

Comment: so, what can I do?

Comment: it's done, it was a bug of my computer

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the askubuntu page shown below, it should be helpful, at least somewhat. As long as you are ok with terminal. Good luck.

[Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter not working on Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419867/qualcomm-atheros-ar9485-wireless-network-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: I haven't 13.10 I have 14.04 LTS so isn't the same

Comment: Can you find out if the wireless card is compatible with 14.04? I think that might be the problem. If so, I would just get a new card that fits into your PC. If you do get a new card, make sure it works with your Ubuntu version. Another problem could be your kernel. Find out the linux kernel that you have and see if the card works with the kernel, too. Good luck